# Mapper Attachment to Kibana issues

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have created some index in `Elasticsearch` with mapper attachment plugin. However, when I try to create index in `Kibana`, I could not find back any data created in `Elasticsearch` for making dashboard in `Kibana`

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running http://:9200/_cat/indices?v

The above will return all indexes you have. Once you verified that your mapper attachment index is there, go to `Kibana` at Settings tab and select the checkbox that say your index do not contain time series data. Now write your index name and I hope you find it. Also, make sure your `Kibana` is configured to point to the `Elasticsearch` server your index resides. This is configured in the *config/kibana.yaml*.

Hope I have managed to help!

Comment: Yes, that rocks. It sure helps a lot. Thanks.And, I would wanna create field.raw in Kibana for data in mapper attachment like what the logstash will do for input data with default elasticsearch output template. How can I do that?